# method resolution errors linger even though they are defined in library project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

I have two projects in eclipse. One is a java project I downloaded with SVN, and used Maven to take care of its dependencies. I was able to compile it,and per the instructions I was following added the resulting jar file to another Android project. The later uses Maven also. I had a bunch of errors; took care of most of them by changing the compiler version from 1.5 to 1.6. 
There were two remaining errors about 2 methods, which were not implemented in the JAVA project. I edited that file, and added the method. But my error in the Android project does not go away.
The android project references, and sees the rest of the methods and classes within the java project. Can you help me troubleshoot the issue please? What should I do or check on please? What information do you need to help?

After restarting eclipse the errors went away. I tried restarting before, but seems I had to let eclipse stay shut for a longer period of time.

Now I get the following exception error in logcat when I try to run it:

```
03-25 13:10:19.978: D/AndroidRuntime(31035): Shutting down VM
03-25 13:10:19.978: W/dalvikvm(31035): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415fbc80)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035): Process: org.nick.nfc.seaccess, PID: 31035
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.nick.nfc.seaccess/org.nick.nfc.seaccess.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.nick.nfc.seaccess.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.nfc_extras.jar", zip file "/data/app/org.nick.nfc.seaccess-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.nick.nfc.seaccess-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2131)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.nick.nfc.seaccess.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.nfc_extras.jar", zip file "/data/app/org.nick.nfc.seaccess-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.nick.nfc.seaccess-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
03-25 13:10:19.978: E/AndroidRuntime(31035):    ... 11 more
03-25 13:10:22.318: I/Process(31035): Sending signal. PID: 31035 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Did you try verifying your imports and clean-build the project. and What exactly does the error says? Can you open the jar and see the class file using decompiler to verify you have that method in the compiled class?

Comment: Jimmy, I restarted eclipse and the errors went away. I can not run the app however. I posted the logcat results in the original post.

Comment: have link to the original post?

Comment: Sure Jimmy. Here it is: https://github.com/nelenkov/android-se-access/wiki